# Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. -error

Tags: c#

Following is an attenmpt to write a C# code to find the area of a circle

```
using System;
namespace DataTypeApplication 
{
    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            double area;
            const double pi = 3.14;
            int side;
            Console.WriteLine("enter the radius of circle:");
            side = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            area = (pi * side * side);
            Console.WriteLine("area is {}", area);
}
}
}
```

it gives an error on the line

> side = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

which says

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

What did I do wrong?

Comment: [`double pi = Math.PI;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pi.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you join declaration and assignment of your `side` variable

```
int side = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

it is easy to see that you assign value of type `double` to variable of type `int`

Consider using [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to safely parse string representation of integer or declare `side` as `double`.

Comment: i modified the type of **side** to double. but there is an error during the run(after entering the value for **side**) [link](http://i.imgur.com/PWZHLhV.png)

Comment: you didn't specify a format string properly, `Console.WriteLine("area is {0}", area)`, format string should refer to parameter as`{0}`

Comment: got it. I am learning C# from tutorialspoint.com and the [code](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_constants.htm)

Answer (score -1):

Here, u r taking a value from user and converting it to **Double** using this line of code `Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());`

now what you are doing wrong is that you are storing this Double type value in an INT type variable, now to rectify this either you should declare your variable 'side' as

`double side;`

or type cast ur input value using this

```
side = (double) Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  /*  how to solve this problem

  Error   7   The type or namespace name 'CrystalDecisions' could not be 
  found 
  (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   
  C:\Users\ALI_COM\Documents\Visual Studio 
  2010\Projects\_database_pic\_database_pic\CrystalReport3.cs    14  11  
 _database_pic   */

// now i solved this Problem:
 **properties_> Target Framwork -> .NetFramwork 4**
```

Comment: Try to provide a complete and well-formatted answer.

Answer (score -2):

Convert to int:

```
int side = (int)Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())
```

Comment: While this would technically make the error go away, this is likely not the desired behavior as it loses the `double` precision.